# Angular UI date picker error message in same line

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/3zbpZiItUrFg4n0SWzny?p=preview) I have an Angular UI date picker with an error message that is displayed when the date is invalid. Problem is that the error message is shown below the date instead of the same line. How to fix this?

HTML

```
  <form name="form1" ng-submit="validate(form1)" novalidate>
      <p class="input-group" style="width:160px;margin-bottom:0px;">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="dtFrom" 
               is-open="config1.opened"  uib-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" 
               close-text="Close" name="dtFrom" />
           <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1($event)">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
               </button>
           </span>
      </p>
      <div style="background-color:red;color:white;width:150px"
          ng-show="!form1.dtFrom.$valid">Invalid Date</div>
  </form>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.dtFrom = new Date ();

    $scope.config1 = {};
    $scope.config1.opened = false;
    $scope.open1 = function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
         $scope.config1.opened = true;
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add class `list-inline` in it. 
Here is plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/23CxCMDRK6DBiW115K7T?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are seeing this misalignment is because you are using bootstrap classes but are not correctly applying them to all the corresponding elements. When you use an `input-group` as you've applied to the `<p>` element, you are using a specific bootstrap class that adds styling to the components, like `display:table`. To have a correct behavior for the whole form, you need to keep using these classes on sibling elements. Namely `input-group` and `form-control`. Using these you will notice that its better aligned to its neighbor in both position and height. Additionally its best to wrap all these components in a valid row and column classes for parent elements. I've added an updated version of your plnkr showing how these changes behave:

**[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fau0cr1g2D9CrmJiFMga?p=preview)**